# NGINX HTTP/NON-WWW to HTTPS caused too many redirects

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

I want to 301 redirect all non-https and non-www to `https://www.example.com` using the following configuration I found in another thread as the accepted answer. But it's not working for me.

**What works:**

- `https://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

**BUT...**

- `http://www.example.com` -> TOO MANY REDIRECTS... using curl I can see that this always redirects to itself...

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {

    # ports
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # domain name
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Redirect all non-https requests
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {

    if ($bad_referer) {
        return 444;
    }

    if ($bad_bot) {
        return 444;
    }

    # ports
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    # domain name
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ($host = 'example.com') {
      return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    # ssl certificate files
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.key;

    include basic.conf;
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update**: It's getting even weirder...i've tried to make a general rule to route everything to ssl (as suggested on many blogs)...now www as well as non-www version are redirecting back to itself...

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I have no idea how to debug this...btw...this is a docker swarm cluster...if this helps...

Answer (score 1):

*After testing this myself, I had to edit my original answer because it led to a `conflicting server name` error.*

Sadly I cannot tell you why you still get this redirect loop - maybe the error comes from your include. But I can present you with a working (tested) configuration that accomplishes what you were asking for:

Generally: For rather simple redirecting it is recommended to use the `return` directive instead of `redirect` (https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Goal: 
Whatever combination

- of scheme (`http` or `https`)
- and domain (`example.com` or `www.example.com`)

you type into the browser, you will get redirected to `https://www.example.com`

Heres the configuration:

```
server {

listen 80;

server_name www.example.com redirecttest.de;

return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

server {

listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name www.example.com;

root /var/www/example.com/http;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

}
```

Comment: Ok, so i took your code and did the same for www.example.com and added `if ($scheme = 'http') { return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;  }` but nothing changed...requesting `http://www.example.com` leads to an redirect-loop to itself...

Comment: @LarsDittrich In my opinion you don't need that "if/else".
If you have a look at my serverblock you will notice the following:
No matter what 'scheme' (say: https or http) the user enters in it's browser you will be redirected to https anyways:
return 301 'https://www.example.com$request_uri;'

Comment: I cannot edit my comment anymore: The point is you will get redirected to https anyways, no matter what you initially typed into the browser

Comment: ...but thats not the case...browser says "too many redirects" and curl does that too...but only for the http-www ...any other combination is working...

Comment: I tested what I was proposing first and updated my answer. Please notice, that there is no need for an if-statement to get the redirecting done!

Comment: Nope..it's still not working...but i can't see why your edited code should work anyway...where is the non-www version? Are you sure you cleared the redirect-cache in your browser?